# Bootstrap Datepicker strange sizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using the latest (1.4) version of the [Bootstrap Datepicker from Eternicode](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) on my ASP.Net MVC website. The datepicker works fine but for some reason when I click on the month/year "zoom-out" button, the content is squashed into half the horizontal width of the dropdown. I haven't modified the bootstrap css or js in any way. I've tried using the 1.3 version of the css/js with the same results...

The code I'm using works fine on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/m1zeLLaa/) but not in my local environment.

**HTML**

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text" type="text" class="form-control datepicker input-sm" />
```

**JS**

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: '0,6',
    todayHighlight: true,
    orientation: 'auto'
});
```

The offending element appears to be `<table class="table-condensed">` that spans only half of the dropdown, whereas the parent `datepicker-months` div tag spans the entire width of the dropdown. For `datepicker-days`, I can't see any difference in code but it works fine. `datepicker-years` suffers the same problem as `datepicker-months`

[image: Chrome Web Inspector]

Comment: My best guess with the info you have provided is that your styles are getting overriden by your CSS somewhere. Perhaps there is a plug-in, or otherwise linked CSS file. Why don't you try using the `Web Inspector` or `Firebug` to find out what styles are effecting it and where it's coming from. I can't debug it because the problem cannot be replicated outside of your dev environment.

Comment: @Mastrianni updated question with Web Inspector view of relevant elements. I can't see anything that stands out, maybe requires a fresh pair of eyes...

Answer (score 2):

I just had the exact same issue, and the cause was that I wasn't including the bootstrap-datetimepicker.css in the pages where I was having this issue.

After including it, the month and year views looked normal.

Comment: Meaning I need to explicitly include the css for those pages? I use a _Layout.cshtml to include all of my css resources and this renders all other elements fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just add css:

```
.datepicker table tr td span {
     width: 100% !important;
}
```

You can also use another `width`, but `100%` is the best way to desctop websites.

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same issue, found a style as follows with width set to 30px

```
.datepicker table tr td, .datepicker table tr th{
    text-align:center;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:none
}
```

removing width from above and adding the below css worked for me (different widths for day, month & year columns)

```
.datepicker table tr td.year,.datepicker table tr th.year{
    width:90px;
}
.datepicker table tr td.month,.datepicker table tr th.month{
    width:60px;
}
.datepicker table tr td.day,.datepicker table tr th.day{
    width:30px;
}
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I also had the exact same issue. But eventually what came out was I had a class like below in my stylesheet-

```
table,td{  ../ some styles /..}
```

**Remove** this `table,td{ ..}` class that is overlapping with your datepicker classes.